# NavBar style from Bootstrap 4 not showing in Rails App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, styles, navbar

NavBar style from Bootstrap 4 is not showing in my Rails app. It looks like this [image] .

In my GemFile I am using `gem bootstrap-sass`. When I switch to `gem bootstrap` and I delete `@import bootstrap-sprockets` from `application.scss` file then nav works fine. Why is that? In all tutorials I see people adding `bootstrap-sass` gem and not `bootstrap` gem.

Here is my GemFile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '2.5.0'

gem 'rails', '~> 5.2.1'
gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'puma', '~> 3.11'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.1.0', require: false
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3.5'

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
end

group :development do
  # Access an interactive console on exception pages or by calling 'console' anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end

group :test do
  # Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver
  gem 'capybara', '>= 2.15'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  # Easy installation and use of chromedriver to run system tests with Chrome
  gem 'chromedriver-helper'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

`application.scss` file

```
 @import "bootstrap-sprockets";
 @import "bootstrap";
```

`application.js` file

```
//= require rails-ujs
//= require jquery
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require activestorage
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

Finally my index page is just copied nav from bootstrap site.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the [bootstrap-sass](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass) gem documentation explains, it is only for Bootstrap versions 2 and 3. If you are using Bootstrap 4 styles, you need to use the [bootstrap rubygem](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-rubygem)

Comment: Thank you.

I never questioned validity of `bootstrap-sass` gem since in latest version of ruby-tutorials book that gem is used, so I assumed it was for Bootstrap 4
https://github.com/mhartl/rails_tutorial_4th_edition_gemfiles/blob/master/sample_app/Gemfile